# Show customized label color on bar chart

Tags: java, jasper-reports, jfreechart

I have customized the item label position so that the label appears outside the bar when it doesn't fit inside the bar as shown below.

[image: bar chart]

How do I give a different color to the labels when the text is inside the bar. e.g white color text inside and black color text outside the bar. I have tried the below code but its showing black always. I want 20 to appear in white and 57 and 30 in black text

Note: This is a customizer class written for a *Jaspersoft Studio* bar chart

```
public class Test extends JRAbstractChartCustomizer {

    static class LabelGenerator extends StandardCategoryItemLabelGenerator {
        @Override
        public String generateLabel(CategoryDataset dataset, int series,
                int category) {
            return dataset.getRowKey(series).toString();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void customize(JFreeChart chart, JRChart jasperChart) {

        CategoryPlot plot = (CategoryPlot) chart.getPlot();
        plot.setRangeGridlinesVisible(false);

        BarRenderer renderer = (BarRenderer) plot.getRenderer();
        renderer.setItemMargin(-1);
        renderer.setBaseItemLabelGenerator(new LabelGenerator());
        renderer.setBaseItemLabelsVisible(true);
        ItemLabelPosition p = new ItemLabelPosition(ItemLabelAnchor.INSIDE12,
                TextAnchor.CENTER_RIGHT, TextAnchor.CENTER_RIGHT,
                -Math.PI / 2.0);
        renderer.setBaseItemLabelPaint(new Color(255, 255, 255));
        renderer.setBasePositiveItemLabelPosition(p);

        ItemLabelPosition p2 = new ItemLabelPosition(ItemLabelAnchor.OUTSIDE12,
                TextAnchor.CENTER_LEFT, TextAnchor.CENTER_LEFT, -Math.PI / 2.0);
        renderer.setBaseItemLabelPaint(new Color(0, 0, 0));
        renderer.setPositiveItemLabelPositionFallback(p2);

        CategoryAxis domainAxis = plot.getDomainAxis();
        domainAxis.setCategoryLabelPositions(CategoryLabelPositions.UP_90);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this:

```
import java.awt.Color;
renderer.setBaseItemLabelPaint(Color.WHITE);
```